# How to retrieve callback token for sending emails for API set v1.3

Tags: outlook-addin, add-in, office-js, office365api, outlook-restapi

**Scenario:**

Permission on the Manifest: **ReadWriteMailbox**

We have a outlook add-in that has a button that sends email from the compose mode of OWA/Outlook Desktop add-in. We are doing that by

1. Get the callback token.
2. Get item rest id.
3. Get rest url (which turns out to be https://outlook.office365.com/api).

Making a **POST** call to https://***resturl***/v2.0/me/messages/***restId***/send

dataType: 'json',

**Headers**

'Authorization': 'Bearer ***callbackToken***'

**Problem:**
The email sends successfully in OWA (Outlook Web) but on Outlook 2016 Desktop we get an 403 Forbidden response with

- code: ErrorAccessDenied
- message: The api you are trying to access does not support item scoped OAuth.

**Our Analysis**

As far as we have investigated, Outlook 2016 MSI install does not support v1.5 of API requirement set

see this:
[API requirement set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23KYU.png)

Since, there are two getCallbackTokenAsync methods as per

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5

we are using the one with the isRest option set to true, i.e. the v1.5 one

Our code to get the callback token:

```js
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({
    isRest: true
  },
  function(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === "succeeded") {
      deferred.resolve(asyncResult.value);
    } else {
      deferred.reject("Could not retrieve token");
    }
  });
```

Code to get rest id

```js
function _getItemRestId() {
  // Currently the only Outlook Mobile version that supports add-ins
  // is Outlook for iOS.            
  if (Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName === 'OutlookIOS') {
    // itemId is already REST-formatted
    return Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId || pvt.currentMailId;
  } else {
    // Convert to an item ID for API v2.0
    return Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId || pvt.currentMailId, Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0);
  }
}
```

Code to get the rest url

```js
function _getRestUrl() {
  $timeout(function() {
    notificationService.showInfo('This is the rest URL==> ' + Office.context.mailbox.restUrl);
  });
  console.log('Office REST URL =>', Office.context.mailbox.restUrl);
  return Office.context.mailbox.restUrl || 'https://outlook.office.com/api'; // This is because this requires v1.5 api set requirements which is not yet supported in Outlook for Windows.
}
```

Most Probably,
the getCallbackTokenAsync that executes on Outlook Desktop is that of v1.3 API set and gets us some different token (for getting attachments for an item i guess.) although I am not 100% sure that this is exactly what is wrong with our app.

Will be grateful if I can get a fix to send emails using API v1.4 requirement set.
There is nothing on other forums regarding this and also on the official documentation for that matter.

Comment: Looking at your scenario it seems you need REST access to an item only. In that case use getCallbackToken API without the isRest parameter. That should work for 1.3 and the resulting token will allow you to make an item scoped REST call as well. The isRest=true option returns a token with a much wider scope.

Comment: Also what's the permission level defined in your manifest.

Comment: 1. Permission on the manifest is set to ReadWriteMailbox.






2. When I use the getCallbackToken API without the { isRest: true } option, i.e. the API as defined in api set v1.3 I get the code: ErrorAccessDenied, message: The api you are trying to access does not support item scoped OAuth. on POSTing a call to https://resturl/v2.0/me/messages/restId/send.

Comment: Apologies didn't realize that you are trying to send an email instead of accessing an item. This behavior is by design since an item scope token will only allow you to access an item. Sending mail is a different operation that requires additional permissions. With isRest = true you get a token that has Mailbox.Send permission that allows you to perform the send operation. However it does require req. set 1.5 which is not supported on 2016 MSI and 2013.

Comment: A work around can be that if the client does not support 1.5 take the user through the oAuth login flow. That will get you the access token that has the Mail.send permission. For the next login you can map the AT/ RT to the exchange identity token so that user is not required to re-login.

Comment: Following link has additional information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authentication